# Inserting the data returned by another function to the Mysql database in python

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x

Firstly I have a column in table "a" of mysql database which has the name dataindex which goes from 0 to 19. The function "X" which I have wrote will return the value "Z" from o to 19 and based on the value returned by this function I need to pull that data from database. suppose if the function  "X" returns the value of 5 then I need the data from columns a,b,c,d with index 5 from my table"a" in the database.

After getting this data I need to write the data obtained to the another table"b". I have written the code so far for pulling the required data from database and I need to insert this data into the another table. How can I do this?The function insert records is not writing the data to the table_b.

```
def getdata():
    cnxn = dbConnect()
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    final = num_of_work_days()
    qry = "SELECT `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` FROM `table_a` WHERE `dataindex`=%s"
    cursor.execute(qry, (Z,))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cnxn.commit()
    return result
print(getdata())

def insertrecords():
  cnxn = dbConnect()
  cursor = cnxn.cursor()
  result = getdata()
  sql ="""INSERT INTO table_b (a, b, c, d) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
  cursor.execute(sql, (result))
  cnxn.commit()
print(insertrecords())
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors but simply I am not able to see any data inserted in the database.